# How do I avoid StackOverflow due to circular dependencies in a FSM?

Tags: c#, fsm

I have a FSM defined as the following which essentially iterates though the actions in the current state and transitions to another state depending on the result of calling the Act function on the current action.

```
public interface IAction
{
    public abstract IState Act();
}

public interface IState
{
    public IAction[] Actions { get; }
}

public class StateController
{
    public IState CurrentState; 

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var action in CurrentState.Actions)
        {
            var state = action.Act();
            TransitionToState(state);
        }
    }
        
    private void TransitionToState(IState nextState)
    {
        if (nextState == null || nextState == CurrentState)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        CurrentState = nextState;
    }
}
```

If I have start implementing my states and setting their actions then things get ugly pretty quickly as I set one of the return states of the LookAction to a new instance of SleepState which itself sets a return state to a new instance of WakeState.

```
public class WakeState : IState
{
    public IAction[] Actions { get; }

    public WakeState()
    {
        Actions = new IAction[]
        {
            new LookAction()
            {
                TargetNotVisibleState = new SleepState() // StackOverflow as this calls SleepState instantiates WakeState in its constructor
            },
            new WaitForTimeElapsedAction(2f)
            {
                TimeElapsedState = new AttackState()
            }
        };
    }
}

public class SleepState : IState
{
    public IAction[] Actions { get; }

    public SleepState()
    {
        Actions = new IAction[]
        {
            new LookAction(true)
            {
                TargetVisibleState = new WakeState()
            },
            new WaitForTimeElapsedAction(2f)
            {
                TimeElapsedState = new ScanState()
            }
        };
    }
}

public class LookAction : IAction
{
    public IState TargetVisibleState;
    public IState TargetNotVisibleState;
    public IState TargetOutOfRangeState;

    public IState Act()
    {
        if (TargetOutOfRange())
        {
            return TargetOutOfRangeState;
        }

        return CanSee() ? TargetVisibleState : TargetNotVisibleState;
    }

    ...
```

How would it be best to avoid this without losing the ability to set any State for the return state in an Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create all your states first, only once they're created you hook them all together. So it means that your state constructors do no create new states, you let your state machine do the creation and the connection.

Another pattern that you could use is to construct all the states upfront, then do a "finalize initialization" pass at it, where you supply all the states that exist and let the states finish up their own initialization (pseudocode):

```
var states = dict(name, IState);

states["WakeState"] = new WakeState();
states["SleepState"] = new SleepState();
states["AttackState"] = new AttackState();

foreach ( var state in states ):
  state->finalizeInit(states);
```

With finalizeInit:

```
class SleepState : IState
{
    public void finalizeInit(dict(name, IState) AllStates)
    {
      
      Actions = new IAction[]
        {
            new LookAction()
            {
                TargetNotVisibleState = AllStates["SleepState"]
            },
            new WaitForTimeElapsedAction(2f)
            {
                TimeElapsedState = AllStates["AttackState"]
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Yet another option is to let the states tell the state machine which state to go to next by its identifier, not by setting explicit a new state. (pseudoc#)

```
public class StateController
{
    public IState CurrentState; 
    private dict(StateName, IState) AllStates;
    
    public StateController()
    {
      AllStates["WakeState"] = new WakeState();
      AllStates["SleepState"] = new SleepState();
      AllStates["AttackState"] = new AttackState();
      CurrentState = AllStates["SleepState"];
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var action in CurrentState.Actions)
        {
            var stateName = action.Act();
            if ( TransitionToState(state) )
              break;
        }
    }
        
    private void TransitionToState(string nextState)
    {
        if (nextState == "" || nextState == CurrentState.name || AllStates[nextState] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        CurrentState = AllStates[nextState];
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll neet to adapt your states and actions to use strings instead of states:

```
public class WakeState : IState
{
    public IAction[] Actions { get; }

    public WakeState()
    {
        Actions = new IAction[]
        {
            new LookAction()
            {
                TargetNotVisibleState = "SleepState" // StackOverflow as this calls SleepState instantiates WakeState in its constructor
            },
            new WaitForTimeElapsedAction(2f)
            {
                TimeElapsedState = "AttackState"
            }
        };
    }
}


public class LookAction : IAction
{
    public string TargetVisibleState    = "";
    public string TargetNotVisibleState = "";
    public string TargetOutOfRangeState = "";

    public string Act()
    {
        if (TargetOutOfRange())
        {
            return TargetOutOfRangeState;
        }

        return CanSee() ? TargetVisibleState : TargetNotVisibleState;
    }
}
```

With these two last options, you'll need to know all the states that exist beforehand because you'll need to create them all from your state machine, but they still give you the option to let the States decide "where to go next".

---

It seems odd to me that you allow multiple changes of state during the same frame.

You may want to prevent this by allowing only one change of state during the frame:

```
    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var action in CurrentState.Actions)
        {
            var state = action.Act();
            if ( TransitionToState(state) )
              break;
        }
    }
        
    private bool TransitionToState(IState nextState)
    {
        if (nextState == null || nextState == CurrentState)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        CurrentState = nextState;
        return true;
    }
```

Alternatively, you could add a timer during which the state cannot change to another state.

Comment: I thought about this but the IState interface would need to allow for a set accessor which I’m not sure I’m keen on.  Would rather have the actions be immutable. The foreach action loop is a bit scrappy though, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @user1423893 I have edited my answer with a bit more options.

Comment: I've gone with instantiating all states in the FSM with a string lookup.  Part of me would like a more elegant way but it makes sense to know all states ahead of time and the actions still have the ability to return different known states.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: The thing that is bothering me is that if the State instantiated once then things that accumulate in the State Action(s) such as a counter are not reset.  This can be handled by calling Reset on the Action(s) during a transition but it does not sit right with me.

Comment: @user1423893 a typical way to approach this is to add an OnEnterState and OnExitState that are called once when changing state. You "prepare" the state in OnEnterState, and you clean it in OnExitState.

Comment: Using an interface for state (IState) would result in each State instance having to implement a call to Reset on each Action using that approach. Seemed cleaner to write it once in the state machine itself.